# 60fps not met even though frame's tasks are 8ms

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, css-animations

I'm playing around with Google's Developer Tools Timeline. I have an animation:

http://output.jsbin.com/yecudotija/1

& timeline from my machine:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0opclvbvb82ff8f/TimelineRawData-20151229T130820.json?dl=0

(I'm using Chrome 47) and even though time required for all tasks is 8ms, whole frame is 26ms - so 60fps is not meet and I have a junk:

[image]

[image]

Any idea why is that?

Comment: Without a demo I don't see how we could *possibly* answer this.

Comment: There you go, i've updated the question. However I thought that it has more to do with how frames are rendered and screenshots would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have jank, because you have *one* massive layer being repainted each frame. It is almost 12000 pixels long. You need to find a way to minimize this.

To figure this out, turn on "Paint" profiling and turn off the rest. Then just run a quick 2-3 second profile. It will take a bit to calculate the data since the frame is so big.

Once that comes up, click on the frame and check the layer panel for it. That shows the massive frame which is a good indicator of where painting is occuring.

Another drawback is, you have tons of `.box` divs, all with `will-change`. This is exactly how will-change was **NOT** meant to be  used. Not all of these divs are changing. So you are giving a bunch of noise to the engine and it is doing a lot more work than needed. Be absolutely specific about what will-change is applied to and what for. You are also telling it you are changing it with a transform, which never happens. So if the engine is doing anything with all the noise created, it isn't helping at all.

On the note of your alterations also, background-color causes [repaint and re-composition](http://csstriggers.com/#background-color). You should avoid modifying it and instead find alternative methods (like modifying the opacity of the element or between two elements) in order to get the same result.

[image: massive-frame]

### tl;dr

1) Avoid huge layers. They are very costly.

2) Avoid numerous uneeded layers (like all these  `.box` divs.)

3) Use `will-change` against only elements that will actually change.

4) Provide will-change the proper thing that is changing. So engines do the best work they can.

5) Try to avoid modifying background-color.

Comment: This is just an exercise code from one of the online courses. Thx a lot for great answer!

Comment: One question though: why in my timeline (eg. 26ms frame) most of the time is "idle" (only 8ms is real job) ? I mean it does not give any hints that any one or other operation is time consuming.

Comment: I also played around with opacity. Here're two versions (animation with background color & opacity change). When looking at the timeline I see no difference, both trigger layout & paint: http://output.jsbin.com/tixaloq/12 & http://output.jsbin.com/tixaloq/14 . Am I still doing it wrong?

Comment: You don't just append opacity changes. You still are incurring a repaint from the background-color change of the element. You'd literally stack two elements. Grey on top of the white. Then set the grey opacity to 0 and change that to 1. Remove the opacity part and this should be just fine. It is within the 16ms boundry.

Comment: Hmm, i don't quite get it: elements[i].classList.toggle('grey-toggle') , which is triggered every frame, only changes the opacity. background-color is constant all the time, or am i missing something?

Comment: Ah, I was misreading the setup (trying to do it via elements panel while everything is going on.) Yea, it's fine. you are in the perf boundary. [This jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pegajehoti/edit?html,css,js,output) is optimized a bit more. Doing less logic in each loop, will-change on the boxes. Beyond this you aren't going to get much better. This is not triggering layout  from what I can tell, just recalc style (from the toggle) and then repaint (from the opacity change.)